# Why wont my .UWP emulator launch in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.uwp

I am creating a fairly simple app to just understand the basics of Xamarin and SkiaSharp etc. Basically, just a ball moving across a background, but when I try to run my code to see what happens in the emulator, it gets stuck loading, and when I jump back to Vis. Studio the emulator crashes.

My code is this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Ball_Bounce
{
   public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
   {
       int posX = 0;
       int posY = 0;
       int dx = 5;
       int dy = 5;
       int ballD = 100;
       bool running = true;
     

                       

       SKPaint blackFillPaint = new SKPaint
       {
           Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
           Color = SKColors.Black
       };

       SKPaint Ball = new SKPaint
       {
           Color = SKColors.Black,

       };
       public MainPage()
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1f / 60), () =>
              {
                  CanvasView.InvalidateSurface();
                  return true;
              });
           
       }

       private void CanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
       {
           SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
           SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
           canvas.Clear(SKColors.SteelBlue);
           int width = e.Info.Width;
           int height = e.Info.Height;
           canvas.Translate(width / 2, height / 2);

           do
           {
               posX += dx;
               posY += dy;
           } while (running == true);

           canvas.DrawCircle(posX, posY, ballD, blackFillPaint);
           


       }
   }
}
```

Before I added the part declaring variables:

```
        int posY = 0;
        int dx = 5;
        int dy = 5;
        int ballD = 100;
        bool running = true;
```

And later this:

```
            do
            {
                posX += dx;
                posY += dy;
            } while (running == true);
```

It would launch and show the nice slate blue background and black ball (I had launched without the variables declaring where to draw the ball and used integers instead.) but as soon as I tried to have the ball traverse across the screen, it wouldn't launch at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your `do..while` loop will never exit, it just spins forever eating up your system resources until the OS kills it

Comment: @Jason - ok so that makes sense, and after doing a bit more research I discovered the Translate function in Xamarin, but I don't quite understand how to use it. Would using that function do what I want it to do? (move the ball across the screen)

Comment: No idea.  What you're doing may be OK, but you only need to animate **one frame** each time the timer fires.  There is no need for a loop.

Comment: @Jason - I removed the loop and it worked :) Thanks!

Comment: @JonTheBrownDog Hi, if you have solved that, you could share the solution as an answer, then others who have the same issue will know that.

Comment: @JonTheBrownDog Hi, thanks for updating the answer. You could mark that when you have time, it will be helpful for others who meet the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

your do..while loop will never exit, it just spins forever eating up your system resources until the OS kills it ...you only need to animate one frame each time the timer fires. There is no need for a loop. @Jason

Removing the loop means that the emulator can render the image and it refreshes the code by itself, like it's its own loop built around the code.